# String input with line breaks to arrays

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an string input like this:

```
2 4 6
1 2 3
2
1
0
```

how to save every line as an array? I use

```
input = input.split("\n");
```

which give me:

```
 [['2', ' ', '4', ' ', '6'], ['1', ' ', '2', ' ', '3'], ['2'], ['1'], ['0']]
```

then i looped every array with regex:

```
var arr = ['2', ' ', '4', ' ', '6'];
var reg = /[^\s]/g;
var arr2 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].match(reg)) {
        console.log(arr[i]);
        arr2.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
arr = arr2; // arr = [ '2', '4', '6' ];
```

and so on. Is there any faster way to do that? I've tried complex regex, but I failed. Input is always 4 lines.

Comment: I think all you need is `input.match(/\d+/g)`

Comment: Or `input.split(/\D+/)`

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you replace line breaks with spaces and then split into spaces?

```
var arr = input.replace(/\n/g,' ').split(' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split once for the \n and one for the space:

```
var input = "2 4 6\n1 2 3\n2\n1\n0";
input = input.split("\n");
for (var i =0; i<input.length; i++) {
   var tab = input[i].split(" ") ;
    alert(tab.join("-")) ;
}
```